# SELECT * from main table including foreign key related table

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables.

```
Table A
a_id, a_name, a_description, b_id

Table B
b_id, b_name, c_id

Table C
c_id, c_name (c_name is unique hence no duplicates)
```

Table "A" has a foreign key 'b_id' to Table "B". Table "B" has foreign key 'c_id' to Table C

I want all Rows of table "A"(No where clause). Each row has 'b_id' so i also need row detail of that foreign key in Table "B". And row details of 'c_id' too.

How can I implement this in an efficient single query? I was using three separate queries and merging result in php. Code looked complicated. I know there is simpler and efficient way since I have just started MySQL.

I am making API that gets all these data and sends to my app.

Edit:

- I am doing "SELECT *" from Table "A"
- Then I am iterating the array of rows and running "Select b_name from
  Table B where b_id = a.b_id"
- then "Select c_name from Table B where c_id = b.c_id"

I am merging array result in the end.

What I need in result is * columns from Table A, 'b_name' from Table B and 'c_name' from Table C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you need to use `join`

```
Select A.*,B.b_name as b_name,C.c_name as c_name
from A left join B on A.b_id = B.b_id left join C on B.c_id = C.c_id
```

Comment: Thanks. I understood what its doing. How would i get name column for "B" and "C" too ? Right now i am getting A.* only

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked but with slight modification. I had to remove "as b_name" and "as c_name". Could you please explain it so i could learn it? Thanks again.

Comment: Here `as b_name` and `as c_name` is been used as an [alias](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) for identifying those values with better user defined notations. You can learn more about joins over [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use `JOIN`, for example:

`SELECT A.a_id, B.b_id, C.c_id FROM A JOIN B ON A.b_id = B.b_id JOIN C ON B.c_id = C.c_id`

More info: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp